# how to integrate sailsjs with vuetify?

Tags: sails.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to use vuetify component like tables in my sails project. I can get the UI working fine, but all actions (button clicks) are not working unless I disable parasails for that page. Anyone has experience integrating sails with vuetify?

Comment: You should describe what you already tried and what are your config files

Answer (score 1):

I followed this example:

https://github.com/ndabAP/vue-sails-example

But instead of using vue-bootstrap I did with Vuetify with the vue-cli:

```
vue create frontend
cd frontend
vue add vuetify
```

And in the vue.config.js I used:

```
// frontend/vue.config.js
outputDir: "../backend/assets/dependencies",
```

In the backend generate a controller route to index.js:

```
// config/routes.js
'/*': { action:'index', skipAssets: true, skipRegex: /^\/api\/v1\/.*$/ },
```

with the content:

```
// controllers/index.js
module.exports = {
  friendlyName: 'View homepage',
  description: 'Display homepage view',
  exits: {
    success: {
      statusCode: 200,
      description: 'Display the view index page.',
      viewTemplatePath: 'pages/index'
    },
  },
  fn: async function () {
    return {};
  }
};
```

The view layouts/layout.ejs should content:

```
<% /* views/layouts/layout.ejs */ %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%=typeof title == 'undefined' ? 'New Sails App' : title%></title>
    <!-- Viewport mobile tag for sensible mobile support -->
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel=icon href=/favicon.ico>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <!--STYLES-->
    <!--STYLES END-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but frontend doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id=app></div>
    <!--TEMPLATES-->
    <!--TEMPLATES END-->
    <%- exposeLocalsToBrowser() %>
    <!--SCRIPTS-->
    <!--SCRIPTS END-->
  </body>
</html>
```

And that is the better way that I figured it out. If there is another simplest way I want to know, because I think that is necessary modifying parasails.js to upload components directly or change the form of registering pages by registering components instead, using a unique page in a similar way.